# How to enumerate all hard link paths of a certain inode without traversing an entire filesystem in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, hardlink

I would like to know all paths that has the same inode number, I found [ls - List all files with the same inode number? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73538/list-all-files-with-the-same-inode-number) however the answer involves traversing the entire inode-containing filesystem using the `find` utility, which is not practical for filesystems with large number count of files.

Since the hard link information should be stored in a file system's certain data structure, is it possible to retrieve such information with a file system-specific utility directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would only be possible if the inode itself contained the location of every linked object. This is impractical because it requires several more updates (and validation steps) to the inode itself in the case that one of the files is moved in the directory structure. Having actual file paths in the inode would mean a lot more overhead in the inode as it would have to dynamically change its size to compensate for path changes or renames and the inode size could vary wildly.

Instead the inode contains only the number of links, not where to or from. This number of links could be a single 32 bit field and does not cause the inode size to change, it can be updated "in place" rather than the whole item needing to be loaded, modified and then saved again in a different place.

The only places where the inode number is listed is in the directory object itself. Bear in mind that directories are essentially just special files that link other files together. That way for a file move the number of links remains the same and it is just a couple of directory updates. For a delete or add it is a directory change and a minor update to the inode.

As a result the only way is, as you have found, to traverse the entire filesystem searching for occurrences of that inode.